# how to install python packages locally inside virtual environment

Tags: django, virtualenv

I am trying to install packages from my requirements.txt file but I am getting this error, it's interesting because I don't have any project dependency as such and I have already ran

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**error I am getting**

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_sass'
```

*I want to install these dependencies such that they should be local only to the project I am working on, any idea how to achieve that ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a virtual environment for installing it for project-specific.
For that, you will require virtualenv package. You can download it using:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Once done, move to your project directory and create virtualenv using:

```
virtualenv <your_environment_name>
```

Like if you wants to create environment named my_env. The command goes like:

```
virtualenv my_env
```

Now activate your virtualenv.
If you are on windows, activate using:

```
.\my_env\Scripts\activate
```

If you are on Linux:

```
source my_env/bin/activate
```

Now install your requirements.txt using:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install dependencies for one project without messing up your global setup, you can use virtualenv:

- Install virtualenv
- Create a virtual environment (in your project directory)
- Activate that virtual environment
- and then install your packages

Just follow the tutorial on this website: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Comment: For a valid answer, copy the few actual commands needed right here.